# Difference in Difference (DiD) estimator in cross country studies

Tags: multiple-regression, experiment-design, difference-in-difference, observational-study

How can we use Difference in Difference (DiD) estimator in cross country studies where we have to interpret results for each country separately?

Should this be one model using country dummy and country * explanatory interaction term(s)? Or different models for each country separately?

Comment: Hi -- could you explain what you mean by "interpret each country separately"? I'm assuming you mean report the change/difference for each country.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes you are right a kind of cross country analysis  E.g to study the impact of binary treatment on an outcome and treatment effect will be conditioned on institutional factors that  differ across countries..